# Android app - share intent fatal error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, share

```
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.androidma.voteq.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:271)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at     android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu    (ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
07-27 11:29:26.390: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
```

When i tried to insert "share" action on to action bar, my app is crashing.

the line with problem is this

```
    myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
```

this class is in my imports:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

my main activity class starts like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

my code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);



        ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();



        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        startActivity(myIntent);

        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Oylamaya Katil! Google vs. Apple! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=tr");

        myIntent.setType("text/plain");



        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);

    return true;



}
```

the main.xml in the menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"

        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

        android:title="Share"

         android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />



</menu>
```

action manu share munu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"

        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

        android:title="Share"

        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />



</menu>
```

when i use the share intent code block it will run on another project.
i coulnd't be able to solve this for hours...

this solved my problem:

```
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);

        final MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)       MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);



        Intent myIntent = new Intent();

        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Oylamaya Katil! Google vs. Apple!     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=tr");

        myIntent.setType("text/plain");



        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);







        return true;



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half of your code is using the AppCompat action bar backport. Half of your code is using the native API Level 11+ action bar implementation. This will not work. Choose one and stick with it.

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> This guide focuses on how to use the support library's action bar, but if your app supports only Android 3.0 or higher, you should use the ActionBar APIs in the framework. Most of the APIs are the same—but reside in a different package namespace—with a few exceptions to method names or signatures that are noted in the sections below.